# How to get top n % and button n% in data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id    val1    val2    vt
1   14  12  19
2   13  13  12
3   12  12  13
4   12  13  13
5   12  14  22
6   12  12  14
7   12  13  14
8   12  14  12
9   13  13  14
10  13  14  14
11  14  14  14
12  13  14  17
13  13  14  31
14  13  13  14
15  13  14  13
16  13  14  23
                
", header = TRUE)
```

I want to get the top 25 % and the bottom 45% according to vt.

Here is the output
top25%

```
id  val1    val2    vt
13  13  14  31
16  13  14  23
5   12  14  22
1   14  12  19
```

and the top 45% is

```
id  val1    val2    vt
7   12  13  14
9   13  13  14
10  13  14  14
11  14  14  14
14  13  13  14
3   12  12  13
4   12  13  13
15  13  14  13
2   13  13  12
8   12  14  12
```

I have tried subset() with quantile, it seems it does not work for the bottom n%.
Is it possible to do it with dplyr? I have checked the other links, they have not provided for the bottom n%. In addition, I do not want to get them by any group.

Comment: PLease check the `slice_max` and `slice_min` function from the tidyverse.

Comment: I Have edited the questions. Please open it if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr::slice_min()` and `dplyr::slice_max()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <- read.table(text = "id    val1    val2    vt
1   14  12  19
2   13  13  12
3   12  12  13
4   12  13  13
5   12  14  22
6   12  12  14
7   12  13  14
8   12  14  12
9   13  13  14
10  13  14  14
11  14  14  14
12  13  14  17
13  13  14  31
14  13  13  14
15  13  14  13
16  13  14  23
                
", header = TRUE)

df %>% slice_max(order_by = vt, prop = 0.25)
#   id val1 val2 vt
# 1 13   13   14 31
# 2 16   13   14 23
# 3  5   12   14 22
# 4  1   14   12 19

df %>% slice_min(order_by = vt, prop = 0.45)
#    id val1 val2 vt
# 1   2   13   13 12
# 2   8   12   14 12
# 3   3   12   12 13
# 4   4   12   13 13
# 5  15   13   14 13
# 6   6   12   12 14
# 7   7   12   13 14
# 8   9   13   13 14
# 9  10   13   14 14
# 10 11   14   14 14
# 11 14   13   13 14
```

Comment: If you have similar values, it does not properly slice the top and button n%

Comment: @user330 Could you elaborate?

Comment: For example, if 31 appears 5 times, you get 5 rows instead of 4 rows,

Comment: So you don't want identical `vt` values to be treated as distinct (values)?

Comment: The identical values are not an issue. I want to code behave correctly. For example, if we have 16 values, it needs to slice 4 at the top and 4 at the butoom

Comment: @user330 I'm sorry but I'm completely lost now. Could you please illustrate *clearly* what your expected output is by updating the OP with an example? From what I can parse of it as it stands right now, you have the expected outputs in there--and my solution here matches that. If I am mistaken, please do correct me. Your recent comment does not really compute w.r.t. your originally stated objective.

Comment: @user330 wait, what? Why? The solution doesn't address your problem though? (Or does it?) You should not accept the answer if it hasn't actually solved your problem, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `findInterval` + `quantile` like below

```
res <- with(dat, split(dat, findInterval(vt, quantile(vt, c(.45, .75)), left.open = TRUE)))
res_45bottom <- head(res, 1)[[1]]
res_25top <- tail(res, 1)[[1]]
```

such that

```
> res_45bottom
   id val1 val2 vt
2   2   13   13 12
3   3   12   12 13
4   4   12   13 13
6   6   12   12 14
7   7   12   13 14
8   8   12   14 12
9   9   13   13 14
10 10   13   14 14
11 11   14   14 14
14 14   13   13 14
15 15   13   14 13

> res_25top
   id val1 val2 vt
1   1   14   12 19
5   5   12   14 22
13 13   13   14 31
16 16   13   14 23
```